# Redirect with .htaccess all files in subdirectory but exclude the subdirectory itself

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all urls like this

www.example.com/uploads/video/video1.html to  www.example.com/video1.html

www.example.com/uploads/video/video2.html to  www.example.com/video2.html

But would like to keep www.example.com/uploads/video/ as it is.

I'm using this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^uploads/video/$
RewriteRule ^uploads/video/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this is still redirecting also www.example.com/uploads/video/ to www.example.com/

Is there any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. The `*` means zero or more characters which is why it matches uploads/video/. If you use the `+` it looks for one or more, which means your rule will require there to be something after uploads/video/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^uploads/video/$
RewriteRule ^uploads/video/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: perfect it's working, thanks. Just one question, also if * matches uploads/video/ why the RewriteCond was not excluding this URL from the rewriterule?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/video/$` but then you also have to think is there always a trailing slash? If you're not sure make it optional `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/video/?$` But the initial reason why it didn't match was because it was missing the leading slash.